# Spring mvc jsp not rendering

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Getting started with Spring MVC, when I enter my page it loads the welcome.jsp as plain text(just shows source), I know people asked this 1 million times, But I looked over many of the questions and didn't find my solution as most of them using XML and I use java.. I am still not experienced enough to switch between the two.

conf.class :

```
public class conf extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver jspViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        bean.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        bean.setPrefix("/views/");
        bean.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return bean;
    }
}
```

ServletInitializer.class:

```
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {

        return application.sources(Demo4Application.class,conf.class);
    }
}
```

welCont.class (Controller) :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/spring/")
public class welCont {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String wel(ModelMap model)
    {
        model.addAttribute("test","testme");
        return "welcome";
    }
}
```

welcome.jsp :

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>${test}</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think wrong thing is

```
@RequestMapping("/spring/")
```

normally "/spring/" request should go to DispatcherServlet. Not sure in spring boot.

try with this.

```
    @Controller
    public class WelCont {

        @RequestMapping(value="/foldername_if_avaiable/welcome/", method=RequestMethod.GET )
        public ModelAndView wel(
            @RequestParam(value="id", required=false) String id,
            ModelMap model, 
            HttpSession session,
            HttpServletRequest req) throws Exception {

            model.addAttribute("test","testme");

            return new ModelAndView("/foldername_if_avaiable/welcome", model);
        }
    }
```

[reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)